# Filter an image based on subset

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I try to filter an image using this equation:
$$
I_f(x_j, y_k, t)=\sum_{p=-q}^q\sum_{r=-q}^q I(x_{j+p}, x_{k+r}, t) 
$$

where $I$ is the original image in grayscale, $I_f$ is the filtered image and $d$ is the subset. Here, I chose 3. However, I'm confused what will happen when $j=1$, $k=1$, and $p=-q$, $r=-q$.

Looping in MATLAB will result in error:

```
I=rand(240, 320);
[m, n]=size(I);
I_f=zeros(m,n);
d=3;
q=(d-1)/2;
for x=q:n
    for y=q:m
        for r=-q:q
            for p=-q:q
                I_f(x,y)=I(x+p,y+r);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

How to do it correclty in matlab? Is it possible to do it without looping? Thanks in advnace!

Comment: The equation, simply applies a summation mask on the image. It seems you've misunderstand the image filtering. Simply use this code , "q=10;p=10;Mask=ones(q,q);I_f=imfilter(I,Mask);" .You need study image spatial operations.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Sorry I'm quite new in image processing. Anyway, I tweaked the code accordingly. `d=3;Mask=ones(d,d)/9;I_f=imfilter(I,Mask, 'replicate');`

Answer (score 1):

The equation, simply applies a summation mask on the image. It seems you've misunderstand the image filtering. Simply use this code:

```matlab
q=10;
p=10;
Mask=ones(q,q);
I_f=imfilter(I,Mask);
```

This is the comment by [MimSaad](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/17089/mimsaad) converted into an answer.